# C# | Create a json string out of static class fields with values

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I need a method that will be able to loop through every **static property** in a **static class**, and combine these to a string with **json syntax**, where key name would equal to Property name, and key value would be the value of the property.

So the result would be a string with value:

```cs
{ "StaticPropertyName_string": "string_value_of_this_property", "StaticPropertyName_int": 34 }
```

I have a working method that successfully does the opposite - takes a json and maps data to static fields. But can't figure out how to do it in reverse

```cs
    public static void MapProfileToJson(JToken source) //// source = plain json string
    {
        var destinationProperties = typeof(Fields)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        foreach (JProperty prop in source)
        {
            var destinationProp = destinationProperties
                .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(prop.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            var value = ((JValue)prop.Value).Value;

            if (typeof(Fields).GetProperty(prop.Name) != null)
                destinationProp.SetValue(null, Convert.ChangeType(value, destinationProp.PropertyType));
            else
                Console.WriteLine("(!) property \"" + prop.Name + "\" is not found in class... skip");
        }
    }
```

**Example static class:**

```cs
    public static class Fields
    {
        public static bool BoolField { get; set; }
        public static string StringField { get; set; }
        public static int IntField { get; set; }
        public static double DoubleField { get; set; }
    }
```

p.s.
*Key value pairs saved in string, could be wrapped at the end like*

```cs
    ResultString = "{ " + resultString + " }";
```

*C# .NET 4.7.2 (console app)*

Comment: A static class is not a good design choice here. Use the singleton pattern instead so that you have an instance that can be serialized normally.

Comment: That didn't help :) but thx

Comment: It should have.  @madReflection is not wrong.  That said, do you know how to use reflection in C#?  Because this could be as simple as walking the class's members using reflection and simply stitching together a new JSON-compliant string using `StringBuilder`.

Comment: The problem is using a static class in the first place. That's what needs to be fixed. It's a bad design for a *lot* of reasons, and one of them is that serializers don't use static properties. They shouldn't - those properties are *not* part of an object instance, they belong to all instances of a type

Comment: Creating a singleton instance is easy in C# - make the constructor private and add a public static readonly property to the class whose value is the instance you want to share.   You can use a static constructor for the same job. This instance is guaranteed to be created the first time your code tries to access that type

Comment: I understand. But no way to change this approach, that's why Im in search of the solution. App needs to function in stack RAM memory fields, which render all the initialised objects useless, as they're being managed within HEAP. So please kindly avoid commenting if you don't see a solution to this, appreciate it!

Comment: Even better, you can use the `Lazy<T>` class, to lazily initialize the singleton property the first time someone tries to read it, in a thread-safe manner. You can provide a factory method to create the shared value

Comment: @Memo `But no way to change this approach, that's why Im in search of the solution` the  solution is to change this approach. If you really-really need static fields, *don't* serialize the static class. Copy the data into another object and serialize that. That's a LOT cheaper than using reflection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Newtonsoft.JSON very likely uses reflection under the covers, although it might engage in some jiggery pokery to improve performance.

Comment: @Memo: On another note, it seems odd that you can afford the expense of the entire Newtonsoft.JSON library, but not an ordinary class instance.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, its ok for the method to be heavy, but data should be stored in static fields. that's the requirement. Thank you for suggestions

Comment: @RobertHarvey JSON.NET caches the type information so it doesn't have to re-reflect every time.

Comment: Richard Deeming provided a simple and working solution. For all the haters of static fields and methods ^^ = there is always a reason to use one type of approach over another. Before lecturing on "best practise", dare to ask a reason for the choice :) or simply suggest a solution if you're so lectured. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, a `static` class is not a good design here.

However, it *is* possible to map it back to JSON with some simple reflection:

```
public static JObject MapStaticClassToJson(Type staticClassToMap)
{
    var result = new JObject();
    var properties = staticClassToMap.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
    {
        result.Add(new JProperty(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(null, null)));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's using Newtonsoft.JSON, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, same as in the question. :)

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that.

Comment: Can you show code how to use it , pls? With Fields class for example

Comment: @Serge `JObject json = MapStaticClassToJson(typeof(Fields));`

Comment: @RichardDeeming Thank you very much! I think you mean var json= MapStaticClassToJson(typeof(Fields)).ToString();

Comment: @RichardDeeming that works perfectly! Selecting this as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be nice to have some simple code to assign json properties to a static class properties too. I created this code using @RichardDeeming answer

```
public static void MapStaticClassFromJson(string json, Type staticClassToMap)
{
    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        
    var properties = staticClassToMap.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
    prop.SetValue(null, Convert.ChangeType(jsonObject[prop.Name], prop.PropertyType, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), null);
}
```

test

```
 MapStaticClassFromJson(json,typeof(Data));
 Console.WriteLine(Data.StaticPropertyName_int); 
 Console.WriteLine(Data.StaticPropertyName_string);
```

result

```
34
string_value_of_this_property
```